# How can I make a vertical cut of a numpy array?

Tags: python, numpy, indexing

I am working with a (3200,3200) numpy array, read in from an h5 file.
I already did some calculations on it and then wanted to plot the values of a certain vertical cut.
So for example, all the values on a specific x coordinate.

From what I know using indexing as: `array[:][x]` should give you the x'th column,
but both `array[:][x]` and `array[x][:]` are giving the exact same array, which is the horizontal cut corresponding to `array[x][:]`. I checked if my data is symmetrical, which after looking at the full plot is not the case.

From what I am experiencing it seems to be a bug, because after using np.transpose to transpose the data, the exact same thing happens, but then with the succesfully transposed data.

I tried using the following:

```py
array[:, x]
array[:][x]
```

Also plotting using the index in the `plt.plot` function or outside of it did not change anything.
As:

```py
plt.plot(array[:][x])
```

and

```py
a = array[:][x]
plt.plot(a)
```

result in the same graph.

Comment: Even for lists `[:]` does nothing. It isn't a placeholder for dimension.

Answer (score 1):

So I created small image example you can try:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

example_array = np.random.randint(low=1, high=10, size=(10, 10))
# this is how image will look like
plt.imshow(example_array)

# this what if you cut 3rd column
plt.plot(example_array[:, 2])
```

[:][x] this would not work actually as it already mentioned in the comment section of your question.